# Align an input box at a particular location

Tags: css, alignment

I have a static image as background splash (800x600px), which consists of a blank space at a particular location which needs to be filled with a text box, this splash page is centered for all resolutions (CSS code below)

I am able to align it properly on a particular screen resolution, however when I see it in a different resolution the box moves out of position.

CSS / HTML :

```
.centeredSplash {

    position:relative;
    width:100%; 
       height:100%; 
       background:url(Coming-soon.png) center center no-repeat;

}


.roundcorner{
    position:absolute;
    background-color: #000;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    border: 0px solid #000;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 350px;
    v-align:top; 
    /*bottom:34%;*/
    bottom : 420px;
    right:50%; 
    margin-right: -190px;
}

input
{
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; //For Safari, etc.
    -moz-border-radius: 5px; //For Mozilla, etc.
    border-radius: 5px; 
    float:left;
}

<div class="centeredSplash">
  <div class="roundcorner">
   <input type="text" style="width:269px;margin-right: 10px" id="email"/>    
  </div>
</div>
```

This works fine in certain resoltuions but for higher resolutions the "roundcorner" keeps floating to awkward locations, how can I lock the position  for any resolution, i.e. relative to the splash page image which will always be centered according to the resolution?

Comment: can u share your code in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to center an element with `position: absolute` specified. By some hacks, we can achieve the result but that solution would be more of a patchy work.

In this setup, `.roundcorner` will take its `left` and `right` from its parent which is `centeredSplash` containing your background image.

You can try the following:

```
.centeredSplash
{
    position:relative;
    width:100%; 
    height:100%; 
    background:url(Coming-soon.png) center center no-repeat;
}

.roundcorner
{
    background-color: #eae53f;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    border: 0px solid #000;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 400px;    /*important*/
    margin:0 auto;  /*This will keep your box center in all screen resolutions*/
}

input
{
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; / * For Safari, Chrome */
    -moz-border-radius: 5px; /* For Mozilla */
    border-radius: 5px; 
    width:100px; 
    height:20px;
}
```

**[Working Demo](https://output.jsbin.com/yayonod)**

**Note:** For a block element to remain *horizontally centered* in all screen resolutions, it must have some width specified explicitly otherwise `margin:0 auto` will not work. For aligning vertically centered, we have to do something extra which is a different story. Here is [a complete guide on centering in CSS](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/).